# Run script on WSL2 kernel shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu, wsl-2

I'd like to more gracefully stop Linux processes running on WSL 2. Right now when the kernel stops, it just kills them. Can I register a script to run as the kernel stops?

Comment: I tried everything here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/416299/execute-command-before-shutdown-reboot and that did NOT work. Seems WSL doesn't run the rc0.d when shutting down

Comment: I also tried creating a systemd service (I have debian) as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335022/how-to-run-a-command-before-shutdown-on-ubuntu-21-04 did not work either. Perhaps I did something wrong though